# Postgres - split number and letter

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have a Postgres database with addresses. In there are the streetnames in a Column, also in a seperate column are the housenumber with the letters (if they have one).

Example

```
Streetname               Nr
Haubtstrasse             1
Haubtstrasse             3
Haubtstrasse             3a
Haubtstrasse             3b
Haubtstrasse             5A
Haubtstrasse             5B
```

I need to spilt those 3a and 5A and 5B into:

```
Streetname               Nr   Addition
Haubtstrasse             3    a
Haubtstrasse             3    b
Haubtstrasse             5    A
Haubtstrasse             5    B
```

Can somebody help me with this problem??
like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiNJa.jpg)

Bjorn

Comment: nr is always going to start with number and ends with character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring()` with the pattern argument.  For your supplied examples:

```
select substring(nr from '^[0-9]+') as num,
       substring(nr from '[A-Za-z]+$') as addition
from . . .
```