# Redshift version of substring() function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to split a column of strings that are mix of numbers & letters. Found [Postgres - split number and letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203230/postgres-split-number-and-letter) which is my use case but it doesn't work on Redshift tables.

So, any suggestion how to achieve it in Redshift?

Tried:

```
substring(string from '^[0-9]+') as num
substring(string from '[A-Za-z]+$') as name
```

And got error massage saying specified function is not supported on Redshift tables.

Also, I couldn't get the required result by `SPLIT_PART()` function.

Comment: Try REGEXP_SUBSTR(): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html